# FTP url not working in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to give a link on my SSRS report to a ftp location. For thee same I have dropped a text box on the report and given the link ftp://ftp.mysite.com/file.xls in the Action>>Go to URL setting. I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

However when I run the report and click on the link no action happens. However if I change the link to http, http://www.google.com/ then on clicking the link, a window opens.

So its working with http but not ftp. I verified the ftp location and its correct.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Vipul

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. FTP link does not work in report designer. On deploying the report and then running it, the ftp link started working. HTTP however works even from within the designer which caused the confusion in the first place. I dont know whether its by design but couldnt imagine why it should be that way.